# Force message format when commiting in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, jira

My development team wishes to connect our JIRA issues with our SVN code repository. In order to do this our SVN commits must contain the JIRA issues ID. Is there a way to define a commit message format, so that commits lacking a JIRA ID in their messages will be rejected (in order to avoid micro management after the commit has been entered into the repository)?

As a side note, we are developing on eclipse and use Subverise/Subclipse as our repository related plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse allows to format the commit message if mylyn is used to manage tasks (which I highly recommend)

Window > Preferences... > Mylyn > Team > Commit Comment Template

However, formatting could be enforced on the svn side with pre-commit hook scripts, more info here
http://blog.grimsy.net/2008/07/a-few-svn-pre-commit-hooks/